# Laços de repetição com condições parecem não funcionar

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Obs.: acredito que seja erro nas variáveis, pois os *loops* não funcionam.

Este código armazena o tempo médio de execução dos *backups* de SQL do mês e
utiliza esse tempo para limitar o tempo de execução do *backup*. Se o tempo for maior que a media `* 2 + 60` ele tem que dar *kill* no processo do CMD para fechar outros arquivos de lotes que foram agendados e podem estar sendo executados ou travados.

Fiz através de um contador no `if`, mas não está funcionando os condicionais.

```
echo MONITOR DE ERRO BKUP SQL

@echo on

:: get date
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do (

    set dd=%%i
    set mm=%%j
    set yy=%%k
)


if exist "%temp%\sqldump_elapsed_time%yy%%mm%.txt" (

    set /p sqldump_elapsed_time=<"%temp%\sqldump_elapsed_time%yy%%mm%.txt"

    set /a "tempolimite = (sqldump_elapsed_time * 2) + 60"

    set /a "count = 0"

    pause

:DELAYFUNCTION
    if count LEQ tempolimite (

        if not exist "%temp%\sqldump_bkcup_confirm.txt" (
                TIMEOUT 1 /nobreak
            set /a "count = count + 1"
            echo %count%
            echo %tempolimite%
                goto :DELAYFUNCTION
        )

        if exist "%temp%\sqldump_bkcup_confirm.txt" (
            set /p verificador=<"%temp%\sqldump_bkcup_confirm.txt"
            if verificador=="ok" (
                echo Backup Confirmado - Fechar Programa
                pause
                exit /b
            )
        )
    )

)
>"%temp%\ver.txt" echo %verificador%
echo Backup ERRO - KILL no CMD
pause
REM ESCREVER FUNÇÃO TASKKILL CMD.EXE (PROCURAR COMO ESCREVE)

exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Tente usando variáveis expandidas** com o comando **`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`**

Também remova os espaços antes/depois do**=**ao "setar" os valores para suas variáveis

Detalhe da data, a saída do **`WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day,Month,Year`** é padronizada, o que não acontece com o comando **`date`**, onde o usuário altera o layout da data no sistema.

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cd /d "%~dp0"
cls & mode con cols=62 lines=5 && color 9F & title MONITOR BACKUP SQL ...

rem :|  Cria variavel para data adicionando 0 para dia/mes menores que 10... 
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year^| findstr /r "[0-9]"') do (
     set "data=%%c" & if not %%b geq 10 (set "data=!data!0%%b") else (set "data=!data!%%b")
     if not %%a geq 10 (set "data=!data: =!0%%a") else (set "data=!data: =!%%a") 
   )

:_loop_:
echo/ & echo/Aguardando gerar arquivo: "sqldump_elapsed_time!data:~,6!.txt" & timeout -t 5 & cls
if exist "%temp%\sqldump_elapsed_time!data:~,6!.txt" (

     set /p sqldump_elapsed_time=<"%temp%\sqldump_elapsed_time!data:~,6!.txt"
     set /a "tempolimite= 60 + !sqldump_elapsed_time! * 2" & set "show_t_limit=000!tempolimite!"
     set "count=0" & mode con cols=48 lines=5 ) else ( goto :_loop_:)

     )

:DELAYFUNCTION
cls & echo/ & echo/     MONITOR DE ERRO BACKUP SQL :: !data! & echo/

if !count! leq !tempolimite! (

     if not exist "%temp%\sqldump_bkcup_confirm.txt" (

         set "show_t_count=000!count!" & set /a "count=!count! + 1" 
         echo/   Tempo limite: !show_t_limit:~-4! ^| Tempo decorido: !show_t_count:~-4!
         timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul & goto :DELAYFUNCTION

       ) else (

         set /p verificador=<"%temp%\sqldump_bkcup_confirm.txt" 

         if /i "!verificador!" equ "ok" (

             >"%temp%\ver.txt" echo/!verificador! & goto :kill_cmd:

           ) else (

             color F4 & echo/ & echo/  ERRO: Verificador = "!verificador:~-25!"
             echo/  Backup nao Confirmado^^! - Fechar Programa... 
             echo/  Backup ERRO - KILL no CMD & goto :kill_cmd:

           )
       ) 
   )
   )

:kill_cmd:
timeout -t -1 & taskkill /f /im "CMD.EXE" /t & exit
```